# Conditional aggregation in SQL Server identifying the latest non NULL entry

Tags: sql, iteration, aggregate-functions, ranking-functions

**Starting Point:**

I have a large table with many columns, of which the first is an identifier (ID) and the second a reversed rank over this ID (Rank). Each ID can have an arbitrary number of rows displaying either a NULL or a float value in each column with up to 50+ columns. There is no limiting range for the float values. Below is a small example table already grouped by the ID column.

| ID | Rank | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | 0.7 | 2.7 | NULL | 0.6 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.9 | 1.6 | 0.6 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 3 | NULL | 0.4 | 2.3 | NULL | 0.3 |
| 1 | 4 | 0.6 | NULL | 1.4 | NULL | NULL |

**Goal:**

I want to aggregate this table grouped by the ID, taking the non-NULL values with the highest rank. If only NULL values are found, a NULL value should be used. So the output for the table above should look like this:

| ID | Rank | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 1.4 | NULL | 0.3 |

Standard aggregation functions such as MAX or MIN did not work for me because, exemplarily, in column B they would take 2.7 or 0.6, respectively, and not the correct value (1.4).

My current solution is outside of SQL and iterates for each ID over all columns returning the numeric value with the highest rank or NULL if there is no numeric value for a certain ID.

Any ideas on how to solve this in SQL?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be retrieved using window functions. Since you did not specify a database I used Postgresql. Here is a running example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/68520/1.

```
select 
distinct
"ID", 
max("Rank") over (partition by "ID") "Rank",
first_value("Column_A") over (partition by "ID" order by "Column_A" is null, "Rank" desc) "Column_A",
first_value("Column_B") over (partition by "ID" order by "Column_B" is null, "Rank" desc) "Column_B",
first_value("Column_C") over (partition by "ID" order by "Column_C" is null, "Rank" desc) "Column_C",
first_value("Column_D") over (partition by "ID" order by "Column_D" is null, "Rank" desc) "Column_D",
first_value("Column_E") over (partition by "ID" order by "Column_E" is null, "Rank" desc) "Column_E"
from Table1
```

To create the data I used this DDL / SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
("ID" int, "Rank" int, "Column_A" float, "Column_B" float, "Column_C" float, "Column_D" float, "Column_E" float);

INSERT INTO Table1
("ID", "Rank", "Column_A", "Column_B", "Column_C", "Column_D", "Column_E")
VALUES
(1, 1, NULL, 0.7, 2.7, NULL, 0.6),
(1, 2, 0.9, 1.6, 0.6, NULL, NULL),
(1, 3, NULL, 0.4, 2.3, NULL, 0.3),
(1, 4, 0.6, NULL, 1.4, NULL, NULL);
```

The tricky part here is the use of a window function **first_value** and the needed ordering of values. All values for one **ID** value are sorted descending by **Rank**. Using **"Column_A" is null** for ordering moves all **null** values to the end (at least for Postgresql).

So this SQL results in

| ID | Rank | Column_A | Column_B | Column_C | Column_D | Column_E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 1.4 | (null) | 0.3 |

**Update for SQLServer**

Using SQLServer this **"Column_A" is null** construct is not usable within **order by**. It has to be replaced by **case when "Column_A" is null then 1 else 0 end**. So the SQLServer SQL looks like:

```
select 
distinct
"ID", 
max("Rank") over (partition by "ID") "Rank",
first_value("Column_A") over (partition by "ID" order by case when "Column_A" is null then 1 else 0 end, "Rank" desc) "Column_A",
first_value("Column_B") over (partition by "ID" order by case when "Column_B" is null then 1 else 0 end, "Rank" desc) "Column_B",
first_value("Column_C") over (partition by "ID" order by case when "Column_C" is null then 1 else 0 end, "Rank" desc) "Column_C",
first_value("Column_D") over (partition by "ID" order by case when "Column_D" is null then 1 else 0 end, "Rank" desc) "Column_D",
first_value("Column_E") over (partition by "ID" order by case when "Column_E" is null then 1 else 0 end, "Rank" desc) "Column_E"
from Table1
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing database specification: I'm referencing SQL Server and edited the post.

Your suggestion is quite close, but the is null statement seems to be not working in Server SQL. Any hints on how to adjust your solution to Server SQL?

Comment: @HappyHippo I updated my answer and added the SQLServer specific SQL. Hope that helps. I used SQLServer 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a string based on your `rank` column and the column value and sort it using min or max.

For example, if the highest rank value is 999, you can create from the ranks the following strings:

```
001
002
...
999
```

Then to this new value concatenate `-` and the `column` value. Then we can sort by it. After having the max/min we can remove the not needed part and cast to the original type.

For example, using T-SQL/SQL Server this can be done like the following:

```
SELECT [ID]
      --,MAX([rank])
      ,SUBSTRING(MAX(RIGHT([rank] + 1000, 3) + '-' +CAST(ColumnA AS VARCHAR(32))), 5, 32)
      ,SUBSTRING(MAX(RIGHT([rank] + 1000, 3) + '-' +CAST(ColumnB AS VARCHAR(32))), 5, 32)
      ,SUBSTRING(MAX(RIGHT([rank] + 1000, 3) + '-' +CAST(ColumnC AS VARCHAR(32))), 5, 32)
      ,SUBSTRING(MAX(RIGHT([rank] + 1000, 3) + '-' +CAST(ColumnD AS VARCHAR(32))), 5, 32)
      ,SUBSTRING(MAX(RIGHT([rank] + 1000, 3) + '-' +CAST(ColumnE AS VARCHAR(32))), 5, 32)
FROM #TempTable
GROUP BY [ID]
```

[image]

Also, please note that I am concatenating the value using `+` in order to ensure that if a column has no value, the concatenation will yield `NULL` which will be ignore by the aggregation function.